# How exactly are asynchronous methods implemented

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous

I honestly couldn't find an answer to this seemingly simple question on the web.

How are asynchronous methods implemented? Does it involve creating a thread each time the method is called, or is there a more specialized operating system service for this?

I know that most programming languages have built-in facilities for this (such as an `async` keyword), but I'm asking about the underlying operating system feature that is used.

Comment: Typically asynchronous operations are handled with a cpu scheduler.  What goes on on top of that is entirely dependent on the system you're using.  Concurrent methods will often run on different threads, which the OS knows how to pass off to the scheduler which handles running them.  Things on the computer aren't truly async, it's just the cpu scheduler running a piece here, pausing it, then running a piece there, pausing it, etc.  It happens so fast that it appears to be async to us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special operating system feature for asynchronous methods other than basic multithreading features.  A method's being asynchronous simply means that the caller can move on without waiting for the method to complete.  Sometimes the caller provides a callback function for notification of when the method has completed.

Depending on the programming language, when you write an asynchronous method, you may need to write the thread handling yourself.  For example, the asynchronous method may spawn a new thread to handle the request, or it may queue the request, and one or more other threads may dequeue the requests and handle them.  Note that the "asynchronous" method actually involves a short stretch of synchronous code, in this case to spawn the new thread or to queue the request, with the main task executed asynchronously, typically in another thread.